# Cell's accessory keeps truncating UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I just wonder why a UILabel in UICell gets truncated despite the fact that it would actually fit there.

[image]

I know that accessory indicator takes some space but this is not the point, from what I can see in my storyboard the uilabel would fit there easily. My constraints aren't much stark - There is no trailing space set, just the leading space and vertical alignment.

[image]

Do you have any idea what can cause the truncation of the UILabel? I mean, I know that truncation is caused by the Line Breaks parameter but it's not the point, what is wrong with this free space next to the label that makes it want to break?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

this the piece of code where I set the color, maybe this is something with this frame to achieve gradient color?

```
cell!.cellWorkoutLabel.text = workout.title
    cell!.cellWorkoutLabel.sizeToFit()
    var frameCell = CGRectMake(0,0, 500, 500)
    if(indexPath.row%2==0){
        cell!.backgroundColor = GradientColor(UIGradientStyle.Radial, frameCell, colors)
    }
    else if(indexPath.row%2 != 0)
    {
       cell!.backgroundColor = GradientColor(UIGradientStyle.Radial, frameCell, colors)
    }
```

Comment: You need to make sure you set the **`preferredMaxLayoutWidth`** of the UILabel.

Comment: tried it, didn't solve the problem. This is really weird since I had some previous experience with label in cells in other apps and never encountered such issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set trailing space to the label because bydefault it is taking width that's why its happening . So you need to set it manually.

Comment: I added trailing space >= 2 and it doesn't help

Comment: can you set only 2 not >=2 may b helpful.

Comment: but this is false since I don't want this to be 2, it will push my whole view left.

Comment: In that case you need to set size to fit content

Comment: could you be more specific?

Comment: How can i, you are saying sizeToFit not working so it should work and your problem will be solve.

Comment: damn, I got size class that messed it up, working now, thanks :)